# In string List compare with same name

Tags: c#, list

I have make one list str.

```
List<string> str = new List<string>();

str.AddRange(new string[] { "ahmedabad", "surat", "vadodara", "rajkot", "bhavnagar", "jamnagar", "gandhidham", "gandhinagar" });
```

I have create one class

```
class MatchAddress
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Taluka { get; set; }

            public string District { get; set; }

            public string Pincode { get; set; }

            public float Rank { get; set; }
        }

List<MatchAddress> lm;
List<MatchAddress> lmmatch.
```

fill the lm list.

```
lm.Add(new MatchAddress() { District = "vadodara", Taluka = "vadodara", Rank = 1f, Name = "vadodara" });

lm.Add(new MatchAddress() { District = "gandhinagar", Taluka = "gandhinagar", Rank = 1f, Name = "vadodara" });




foreach (MatchAddress ma in lm)
                    {  
                       string pincode ="";
// what logic i write in below then only we got the vadodara because that name are in both taluka and name then only set nulll if any one differ then not set null.
                      if (str.Contains(ma.Name) && str.Contains(ma.Taluka.ToLower()))
                            {

                                    pincode = null;

                            }

 lmmatch.Add(new MatchAddress() { Name = ma.Name, District = ma.District, Pincode = (pincode == null)? null : ma.Pincode , Rank = rank, Taluka = ma.Taluka });
            }
```

**so in this lmmatch  list for both the MatchAddress object set pincode null but i wan't null for vadodara only and that have same taluka and village name.
if the taluka and name are different then not set pincode null.**

reason behind this is where  in lm list  where pincode and taluka both have vadodara then only set the pincode null .
but this code that i have write  also set pincode null for name vadodara where taluka not same they have gandhinagar.

so after rus this code i have got two object and they both  have set pincode null but i wan't to only for vadodara where they have both name and taluka same.

so any idea how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I see you have a string list str and then you have a List<MatchAddress> lm. Then you iterate through each entry in lm and checking that the ma.Name and the ma.Taluka is present in the string list str. If it is so then you are setting the pincode to null and updating the lmMatch. What is the problem you are facing is unclear.

Comment: Try this .. Make string pincode = ma.Pincode; Also you have two entries in lm which has the name and taluka with the same value. So the lmMatch would have two entries with the pincode as null. If you want only for vadodara then for the other entry in lm change the name or taluka name. In the example you have provided for both the entries the following condition is true ;                                                                                         if (str.Contains(ma.Name) && str.Contains(ma.Taluka.ToLower()))

Comment: ya when iterate through each entry in lm  then i wan't to check in lm list where ma.name and ma.taluka both contain same name then only set null .

Comment: why don't you compare  ma.Name == ma.Taluka ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after, but look into List.Intersect, List.Union, List.Join https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c-sharp%20joining%20lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to change only in your code

```
if (str.Contains(ma.Name) && ma.Name.Equals(ma.Taluka))
```

You Just Need to comare ma.Name = ma.taluka simple

Comment: ToLower() is recommended because it's string comparision.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if as below

```
   if (str.Contains(ma.Name) && ma.Name.ToLower().Equals(ma.Taluka.ToLower()))
```

Comment: @user6807402 - See here for best practices on accepting answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work